# Webkit Animation breaking SVG below it

Tags: css, svg, webkit, css-animations

I have made an example page at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gvs4/1/)

If I enable the `sway` animation on the `#dog` element and scroll the page I see massive banding on the SVG.

If I turn the animation off (delete the `-webkit-animation-name` bit) the banding goes away and the SVG looks like it should (smooth)

Does anyone know what causes this issue? Any way to work around it?

I've only tried in Webkit browsers (Chrome, Canary, both on OSX)

Comment: -webkit prefixed css properties won't generally work in other browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a *very* hacky work-around for this.

Basically you need to repeatedly change the width from the original to the original minus 1 pixel and back again.

```
if($("#svgtest").css('width')=='15500px') {
    $("#svgtest").css('width','14499px');
} else {
    $("#svgtest").css('width','15500px');
}
```

You can see it in action at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gvs4/5/).

Be warned though that it is a hack, not a real fix, but it does solve the SVG banding issue that I was experiencing.

Maybe someone can come up with a slightly less hackish solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the animation triggers the GPU which renders the gradient poorly, the bug can be reproduced by simply applying `translate3d(0,0,0)` on `#test`. http://jsfiddle.net/LKmbN/

Barring [turning off GPU acceleration](http://jamisondance.com/post/22387219496/turning-off-gpu-acceleration-in-google-chrome/) the only workaround I can think of is animating through javascript. Hopefully someone can come up with something less painful.